# Should i create a class that implements an interface or use the interface as it is?

Tags: java, oop, memory-management

In this server app i am extending there is a class EventManager with a method:

```
pubic void addEvent(Event event, int time){ // code to process handling of events }
```

Event is and interface. I have several classes in which i need to run a very similar event that uses a lot of the same methods. Rather than rewriting each of those methods in each of the classes that i am running similar events in, i thought that if i created public class that implements event and had each of the methods in it:

```
public class someEvent impements Event{


    public void send(String message){

          for (int i = 0; i < Server.playerHandler.players.length; i++) {
            if (Server.playerHandler.players[i] != null) {
                    if (Server.playerHandler.players[i].inPcGame()) {
                            Client c = (Client)Server.playerHandler.players[i];
                            c.sendMessage(message);
                    }                      
            }              
    }

    }
    public void spawn(int[] npcs, wave){ 

        int x = 4234;
        int y = 2343;
        int z = 1;
        int health = 10 * wave;
        int maxHit = 5 * wave ;
        int attack = 150;
        int defence = 200;
        NpcHandler.getNpcHandler().spawnNpc(c, 1, x, y, z, 0, health, maxHit, attack, defence, true, false);

   }

    // Event method override
    public void executeEvent(){

         spawn(npcList, waveNum);
         send(message);

    }
}
```

Then use to then create objects in each of the class am running the events in. Then pass those objects to the EventManager.

I taught myself and am still learning, my friend who also taught himself, but has been programming longer says i should do that and should do this instead:

```
import sever.event.EventManager;

public class someClass {

    public void send(String message){

          for (int i = 0; i < Server.playerHandler.players.length; i++) {
            if (Server.playerHandler.players[i] != null) {
                    if (Server.playerHandler.players[i].inPcGame()) {
                            Client c = (Client)Server.playerHandler.players[i];
                            c.sendMessage(message);
                    }                      
            }              
    }

    }
    public void spawn(int[] npcs, wave){ 

        int x = 4234;
        int y = 2343;
        int z = 1;
        int health = 10 * wave;
        int maxHit = 5 * wave ;
        int attack = 150;
        int defence = 200;
        NpcHandler.getNpcHandler().spawnNpc(c, 1, x, y, z, 0, health, maxHit, attack, defence, true, false);

   }

    EventManager.getSingleton().addEvent( new Event(){

        public void executeEvent(){

            spawn();
            send();

    }}, 12000


    );
}
```

and do this in each class rewriting each of the methods in each class i use the event in.

He insists that my way uses more memory and is CPU intensive. I do not understand how my way is heavier on the CPU instead of less intensive than his way. Which way is the correct way and why?

Comment: It sounds like you should ask your friend to justify his opinions, rather than asking us. The pseudo-code you've provided isn't really close enough to being valid code for us to give a good answer, IMO.

Comment: what more information would you need because my friend doesn't have good enough communication skills to provide an answer he just says he is write with out explaining himself.

Comment: I tend to ignore any claims without justification. They provide no value, IMO. In particular, without any explanation you can't reason about which contexts the advice applies to and which it doesn't.

Comment: there, i have fleshed it out more, though mind it is still not got all my code i am just narrowing it down to my specific question, i still have 3 other methods but i question isnt in regards to the methods it is weather i should use objects that implement the interface in each of the classes i need to use this type of an event, or if i should just rewrite each of the methods in those classes instead?

Comment: That's still not valid code. You're calling `EventManager.addEvent` from the middle of a class declaration. We don't need full useful implementations, but valid code would be much easier to reason about. (And I really hope your class names follow Java naming conventions - it's a lot easier to read code when you're not being distracted by unconventional names.)

Comment: i didnt finish the statement because i didnt feel it was super important to the question, but instead semantics, but it is fixed now

Comment: are you writing a game server or a game client? One has a screen, the other doesn't.

Comment: server end is what i am working on right now, the not the client end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you're sorta right and your friend's sorta wrong, though

maybe you're sorta wrong and your friend's sorta right, though


what you want is utility methods in a base class:


what your friend likely wants is for the event manager to have the closure in case of an exception:


Events are exactly the same event every time. They can be the only impetus for a programme; you want to see them up front.

```
class AWholeProgram {

    static EventManager E = new EventManager();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        E.add (  new PhoneCall("15555551212")  );
        E.add(  PrintBatteryLevel  );
        E.add(  PlaySong  );
        E.add(  WaitForIncomingCall  );

    }

    // so the "events", the only things that can happen, are up front...
    final static Event PrintBatteryLevel = ...;
    final static Event PlaySong  = ...;
    final static Event WaitForIncomingCall  = ...;
    final static Event PhoneCall = new phoneCall("15555551212")...;


    class phoneCall extends Event {
        long number = Long.parseString("15555551212");
        phoneCall( String s ) {
          //convert to digits, and look in the phone book, and see if its long distance, etc.
        }
        public void fireEvent() {
           // makes the phone call
        }        
    }

}
```

It makes a **big** difference where the phone number is. If it is tucked away in the event manager class, hehe...

Its really obvious what the program does, 
 also, its really obvious what the program could do,

 and better yet, its really obvious that the program doesn't do anything else.

Many programs kick off with the gui, frames packing and whatnot, and way over in some bit of handler there's a button, which, if clicked deletes a file, or worse. ouch..

Comment: what you wrote seems more like mine than his, and what you are saying though, is that the more layers between eventmanager and the event's code the harder it might be to debug i take it, and i that that as a good point, what i am wondering is the difference in processing and memory?

Comment: You see i am going to need the same type of event in multiple classes, my way seems like it would keep it standardized and the code in one clear place, while his places the code in several places? you have helped clarify a lot of it for me though. considering what you said mine seems better and easier to debug of the the course of places i use the event. Still though what i want to know is does creating the classes instead of directly applying the interface us significantly more memory or cpu usage

Comment: my friend wouldnt be implementing the event in the event manager but repeatedly though out the rest of the program, mine keeps the code in the same place so that in case of an exception i dont have to change the code 15 time in 10 files, but instead have to change it just once

Comment: am i misunderstanding?

Comment: whenever you say 'type of', I think class. whenever you say 'it', 'there', or the 'code', I think object. A class doesn't _do_ anything. Here, you say, "i am going to need the same type of event in multiple classes"; the same event might be used with various objects. Some events will have miniscule differnces, and will be easier to manage as different event classes: Some beep, some log, some include a player, some target a game, etc...

Comment: that clarifies, i will need to use the event in differant objects, the event will only have minuscule differences. he wants the completely rewrite the event in the class for each objct i want to create an class to define the event and then create event objects in each of the other objects

Comment: Hmmm, do it his way. Then, at the end of the coding day, cut and paste all the inline declarations into one file and see if you can't make it easier to reuse by virtue of being better organized. He seems to want to 'write now', which is good, otherwise you can stall trying to be 'optimal'. Knock out some code. Having someone to work with is really valuable, its easier if you each appreciate something that the other person does better than yourself. Calling the event.mgr add method schedules the event. Declaring an event in the main app routine drags all the main app data with it.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want all the events in one file. Yikes.

like this...

```
class BaseEvent {
  // every event logs
  public void fireEvent( Event e ) {
    log.print( event );
  }
  String toString() {
    return getClass.getName();
  }
}

class PlayerEvent extends BaseEvent {
  player p; // every player event has an associated player (and logs, and has a toString method..)
  public void fireEventWithPlayer( Player x, Game g ) {
      g.spawn( x );
      super.fireEvent( this ); ///
  }
}

class GameEvents implements BaseEvent {
  startGame, endGame, createGame, ... 
}

/// just where should the spawn event be?

/// then add the event manager, 
/// a main method that goes through all the steps, so you can see how your logs will look...
/// and at the end pre-define all your events.
/// you'll have **lots** of events in categories (player, game, network, etc.)
```

Answer to question?
implementing an interface the way your friend suggests is almost identical to creating an anonymous inner class which is in scope at the point of declaration. a new instance is created for each call and the quantity of data passed with the "interface method" is dependent on the quantity of data that is in scope at the declaration.

with predefined events the data is low and the cpu is fast. More classes is better than more definitions.

The JVM can optimize the cats off a rug if you declare stuff far enough in advance. Your friend is right, if your were writing in C, or an untyped dynamic language, or even a JVM that couldn't optimize well. Syntactically, you need to keep in mind that the event will run in the event manager's run thread and not at the point where the object is defined.

Comment: you have helped me understand cpu and memory usage for this circumstance, but the other answer works better for the code end, this is more like my sever engine, the eventManager for the code i am working with process events that operate with a different timing that the main engine

Comment: a hundred classes require zero data and zero cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Your method has two variables

addEvent(Event event, int time)

how will it work with a different signature?

Comment: i dont understand your question, also since this isnt an answer, but a question in regards to my question, shouldnt you move it to the comments under my question?

Comment: EventManager.addEvent( public void executeEvent(){ spawn(); send(); } . This signature doesn't matches with the one you mentioned earlier.

Comment: i seen what you were saying after i commented, i didnt finish writing it lol, fixed it now

Comment: `class timedEvent extends BaseEvent { // does something with time, then declares void fireEvent(); }`